# Changing the time and date format

Tags: javascript

I would like to learn how can I run and see the display in this code :

```
var now = new Date();

now.format("m/dd/yy");
// Returns, e.g., 6/09/07

// Can also be used as a standalone function
dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
// Saturday, June 9th, 2007, 5:46:21 PM
```

Thanks.

Comment: please elaborate a little bit. Question is hard to follow.

Comment: It looks like you got this example from http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format.  Just download the script and use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you download the plugin and include it somewhere either in the head of your page, or beneath the body like this

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='pathToFile.js'></script>
```

Next, if you're using a modern browser, you should have a debugger console in which you can test code. If you're using Firefox, take a look at [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), and if you're using Chrome, you already have one, just hit CTRL+SHIFT+J to pull up the console. Once inside of the console, you can enter the commands as you entered them above and see the results. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Back in the old days...**

To view the outcome of your code, you'd traditionally need to make an HTML page and stick that into the `<script type="javascript">...</script>` section of your code.

**Nowadays!**

Nowadays, you can do it right online!
Try plugging your code into this: http://writecodeonline.com/javascript/

**No output?**

you can use `document.write( now );` to display your variable `now` to the screen.

**Still no output?**

I believe that `dateFormat` and `format` will give you errors as JavaScript doesn't know what this is (unless you wrote these methods in your code). [See this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript) for some resources with formatting Javascript Dates.

Comment: This may not work due to the fact that he'll need the plugin to be called into his script.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a library that makes working with dates easier, I recommend [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).